# Fortran PAPIF_stop always reads 0

Tags: fortran, papi

I have a simple program in fortran that uses PAPI APIs to read performance counter values. All APIs (PAPIF_start, PAPIF_stop etc.) all work correctly (meaning, returns PAPI_OK). However, the values that PAPIF_stop reads are always 0. I tried another profiling software on BG/Q to ensure that these values should not be 0. Any idea why this might be the case? This is my first ever attempt at writing a fortran code. So it may very well be a fortran issue that is not evident to me. Will appreciate any help. 
Thanks!
--DE

```
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  subroutine papi_add_events(event_set)
  integer, intent(inout) :: event_set
  include 'f77papi.h'
c     create the eventset
  integer check             
  integer*8 event_code

  event_set = PAPI_NULL
  call PAPIF_create_eventset(event_set, check)
  if (check .ne. PAPI_OK) then
     print *, 'Error in subroutine PAPIF_create_eventset'
     call abort
  end if
  !event_code = PAPI_L1_DCM  ! Total L1 Data Cache misses
  call PAPIF_event_name_to_code('PAPI_FP_INS', event_code, check)
  if (check .NE. PAPI_OK) then
     print *, 'Abort After PAPIF_event_name_to_code: ', check
     call abort
  endif
  call PAPIF_add_event(event_set, event_code, check)
  if (check .NE. PAPI_OK) then
     print *, 'Abort PAPIF_add_events1: ', check, ' ', event_code
     call abort
  endif
  !event_code = PAPI_MEM_RCY ! Cycle stalled waiting for memory reads
  call PAPIF_event_name_to_code('PAPI_TOT_CYC', event_code, check)
  call PAPIF_add_event(event_set, event_code, check)
  if (check .NE. PAPI_OK) then
     print *, 'Abort PAPIF_add_events2: ', check, ' ', event_code
     call abort
  endif

  call PAPIF_start(event_set, check)
  if(check .ne. PAPI_OK) then
     print *, 'Abort after PAPIF_start: ', check
     call abort
  endif

  return
  end

  c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  subroutine papi_stop_counting(event_set, values)
  integer, intent(in) :: event_set
  integer*8, intent(inout) :: values(*) !shows an array

  c     Local variable
  integer check
  include 'f77papi.h'      

  !     stop counting
  call PAPIF_stop(event_set, values(1), check) !*Not sure if it should be values(1) or values*
  if (check .ne. PAPI_OK) then
      print *, 'Abort after PAPIF_stop: ', check
      call abort
  endif

  return
  end
  c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am calling these subroutines from another function like this:

```
  subroutine myfunction

  integer event_set ! For papi
  integer*8 values(50) !For reading papi values
  call papi_lib_init  ! *Not shown, but is present and works. *
  call papi_add_events(event_set)

  do_flops()

  call papi_stop_counting(event_set, values)
  print *, 'Value 1: ', values(1)
  print *, 'Value 2: ', values(2)

  return
  end
```

The output I get is:

```
    Value 1:  0
    Value 2:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/css/staff/rory/papi/papi.php?p=bas

plz **PAPIF_create_eventset** first!

Comment: Thanks, yes I did that already. Turns out, my code is correct. The problem was that I was using papi on BG/Q with BGPM (BlueGene Performance Monitoring) library linked in. So, at the end both Papi and BGPM were enabled and they were not playing nice with each other. My code behaves correctly on Intel machines. Thanks though for your help.